# Reversed binary representation of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binary

I discovered a very interesting fact that if a **prime** is represented in a **binary** form , and if that **binary** is rewritten in the **reverse** order and converted back to **base 10** decimal and if the resulting number is not divisible by **5** or **7** then it is a **prime** or a **square** number or a **product of different primes**

For example:

$(29)_{10} = (11101)_{2}$

Now by rewriting $(11101)_{2}$ in reverse order we get,

$(10111)_{2} = (23)_{10}$

If we perform the same operations other numbers,we get,

$(3)_{10} \rightarrow (3)_{10}$

$(11)_{10} \rightarrow (13)_{10}$

$(17)_{10} \rightarrow (17)_{10}$

$(71)_{10} \rightarrow (113)_{10}$ ($113$ is a **prime**)

$(149)_{10} \rightarrow (169)_{10}$ ($169 = 13\times 13$)

$(151)_{10} \rightarrow (233)_{10}$ ($233$ is a **prime**)

So I was wondering if there are any proofs for this property of primes. 
Can you tell me whether it is true for all primes?

If you could provide any proofs or counter-examples it would be of great help.

Comment: What does the conversion back to base $10$ do? Whether the number is prime is independent of the base. Anyway, you have only checked some very small numbers, which do in general tend to not have many prime factors. Did you check more?

Comment: Yes I did check

Comment: How many did you check?

Comment: There are many counter examples for all of the above, and quite small. For example $(401)_{10}\to (275)_{10} = 5^2\cdot 11$. Just write a script and check by yourself.

Comment: Either a 5 or a 7 is a factor of the counter examples.

Comment: With each edit you've had to water down your question. All you can say is that reversing the binary representation of a number produces a different number. That so many reversals of small primes produce other small primes is just a big coincidence.

Comment: @RobertSoupe This is probably an artifact of choosing a specific base to work in and letting that have an importance. I am not aware of any actually interesting properties related to primes that truly depend on a choice of base (since being prime does not).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What I was getting at is that the OP edited his question for the express purpose of making one of the answerers look foolish. But the joke's on him because a) just look at the answerer's profile, and b) what you just said.

Comment: Robert I am sorry, but  didn't mean to make others feel foolish. It never was my intention.

Comment: Apology accepted. Just a misunderstanding, water under the bridge.

Comment: Downvoting due to dishonest editing after each counterexample which renders the question impossible to answer. It is usually a bad habit to change the question if already answered, you can always ask new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counter examples:

$(607)_{10} \rightarrow (1001)_{10}  = 7 \cdot 11\cdot 13$

$(5689)_{10} \rightarrow(5005)_{10} =5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$

$(135559)_{10} \rightarrow(230945)_{10} =5 \cdot 11 \cdot13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$

Note: My answer has counter examples to an earlier version of the question.

Comment: @VishaalSelvaraj But you already had an example which was a square.

Comment: May be I didn't check enough but there hasn't been a case where the resultant number had different powers of primes

Comment: In your counter examples all prime numbers are different. That's interesting.

Comment: @VishaalSelvaraj  you may like to fiddle with this script. https://jsfiddle.net/ganeshie8/rte8fygg/31/

Comment: Np :) You have some really interesting observations... do feel free to ask if something in that script doesn't make sense

Comment: No, your JavaScript is as clear as day.

Comment: Here is some food for thought  - Either 5 or 7 is a factor for all the counterexamples less than 1000

Comment: @rsadhvika $(241)_{10}\to (143)_{10} = 11\cdot 13$. Line 16 in the script should check $>= 4$ factors to catch semiprimes.

Comment: @nickgard yeah ty, it seems the OP has changed the question. If I remember correctly in an earlier version he was skipping semiprimes..

Answer (score 4):

More counterexamples: $139$ is `10001011`, reversed it's `11010001` which is $209 = 11 \times 19$, not divisible by $5$ or by $7$, not a square. $191$ is `10111111`, reversed that's `11111101` which is $253 = 2^8 - 3 = 11 \times 23$.

You've been fooled by what humans call Richard K. Guy's law of small numbers. Mwahahahaha!

Comment: Yes, answerer, check your answer. Then check the question history.

Comment: Don't worry about me, @Robert. Vishaal did exactly what I wanted him to do. Mwahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you answered before my edit.. Thanks